# How to see list of current connected pc to network?

Tags: windows-7, networking, user, workgroup

I want to list the computers that are connected to network in which I am connected.

Anyone know that how to do so ?

I need this help soon, because I have made my connection open/ password free to know how many computers uses my network.

Any help please.

Comment: Best place would be to check at your router.

Answer (score 2):

You should download and install a program called *nmap*. This is the most effective and secure way to do that. A command like:

```
  nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24
```

will list all pcs on the subnet 192.168.1.0/24 (adapt this to your needs). To get a glimpse of all the things *nmap* can do, issue the command:

```
  nmap -T5 -A 192.168.1.137
```

where you will have to substitute 192.168.1.137 wi the IP address of the pc you want to explore. See how many things *nmap* is capable of unearth for you!

Answer (score 1):

Going to Network (from the left navigation pane on any explorer window, or the start menu), should show devices (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/view-network-computers-devices#1TC=windows-7 ).

However I have found that to be fairly unreliable (devices can choose to not be "discoverable").

Your router however should give you a full list of (directly) connected wifi and Ethernet devices (depends on your router where), although it is technically possible to fool this as well (use a hostname you personally think is OK, or even spoof the address of a system that should be on the network). So from a security standpoint I still wouldn't trust it.

Comment: Incomplete: a router will not display among leases pcs on static IPs, simply because they don't lease anything.

Comment: Depends on the router, mine shows a list of connected WiFi devices by MAC (but not ethernet ones, bit harder to locate currently active ethernet devices, although another I use shows both lists together nicely...) regardless of if the ip address was static or dynamic. Also the DHCP page lists the permanent allocations along with the remaining dynamic leases.

Comment: Your router shows a list of active pcs connected to the network, where active means within a TTL (=Time To Live), which need not be long. A pc might be idle for a longer time than TTL, it would not show in the router list, but it would show up in a nmap scan.

Comment: Perhaps on Ethernet, but for WiFi is it possible for a device to time out and still be considered connected?

Comment: Also dont think nmap will work with some firewall configs (not on a the network right now, but the router/firewall config blocks "guest" devices from communicating with the rest of the subnet, it only allows tcp/udp packets to/from the internet gateway)

Comment: Both statements are incorrect. have you ever noticed that, if you leave your pc alone for a few hours, when you come back you are still connected through wifi? As for firewalls, they obviously pose a problem. But they also pose a problem for all other means of investigation. It is just that nmap has more resources at its disposal, that's all. A lone pc is much more exposed to nmap than to any other instrument of investigation, except of course for other network scanners.

Answer (score 1):

Easier thing would be to check out your Modem/Router's DHCP page for leases. It can usually be found at 10.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.1. You can be sure by using the `ifconfig` command on unix like systems.

Comment: Incomplete: a router will not display among leases pcs on static IPs, simply because they don't lease anything.